# dhtmlx calendar selecting time doesn't change input field

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx

I'm using the dhtmlx calendar to select the date and time. But there's a problem when it comes to selecting the time, the user has to select the date again to 'confirm' the change in time. This is not a normal user behaviour. Is there any way to change the input field straight away when the user selects the time?

There's a onTimeChange method and onChange method but I can't seem to put the changed time into the input field.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to use the following code:

```
myCalendar.attachEvent("onTimeChange", function(d){
    myCalendar.setDate(d);
    myCalendar._updateInp();
});
```